# Hilbert polynomial of structure sheaf of hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, hypersurfaces, hilbert-function

Is there an example of a hypersurface $X$ of some projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that there exists an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$, not isomorphic to the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$, but has the same Hilbert function as $\mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: On a plane curve, any degree zero line bundle (and they exist if degree is at least three) has the same Hilbert polynomial as the structure sheaf, by Riemann-Roch.

Comment: @Mohan Sorry, I should have been a bit more specific. I will edit the question to replace Hilbert polynomial by Hilbert function. Then your example does not hold (only degree zero line bundle with non-trivial global section on a curve is the structure sheaf).

Comment: If $\mathscr L$ has a non-trivial global section, then there is a non-trivial embedding $\mathscr O_X\to \mathscr L$ and if $\mathscr F=\mathscr L/\mathscr O_X$, then $h^0(\mathscr F(n))\neq 0$ while 
$h^i(\mathscr F(n))=0$ for $n\gg 0$ and $i>0$. So, $\chi(\mathscr O_X(n))\neq \chi(\mathscr L(n))$.